# Are Eco-Schools more effective teaching children about sustainability?

Tags: renewables, education

Is there any evidence that [Eco-Schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eco-Schools) are better at building sustainability awareness for school kids and teaching them about renewable energy technologies? Or is there a better approach that might be more effective and faster in developing the awareness for pupils in an attractive way?

Comment: It would be useful to include a brief description of eco-schools in your question. Also, you ask if eco-schools are *better*. Better than what? Perhaps a more meaningful question would be, how effective are eco-schools?

Answer (score -3):

You should teach to reduce energy/resources consumption. Teaching to consume more energy is anti-environmental, despite you heard otherwise from everybody. In is a common misconception on the earth that consuming more (green energy) reduces harmful effects. Capitalists perpetuate this idea because they need consumers. Do you know that when you buy more, you pay less? This is a fallacy of the same kind.

Comment: This doesn't seem related to the question.